# How to fix overlapping materials?

Tags: materials

I was following along with Blender Guru's tutorial on this Chair here, and I got to the point where he begins the UV unwrapping section. I was doing fine until I noticed that once I applied the material, the back of the chair leg now has this overlapping of the material. I heard it is called Z-fighting. I moved the vertices over each other, and away from each other, but no luck. Merging doesn't do anything. When I alt-click, both vertices are selected.

[image: This is what happens when I alt-click one of the two vetices]

The line goes across the whole leg here.

[image: Entire Vertex]

I have tried moving the seams, adding more, removing some, but the problem persists. Also tried to merge by distance, which does work, but not entirely. Some parts of the leg do no overlap, but the rest of the mesh, such as the bottom half of the leg, still has the problem, except this time it is warped.

Here is where it overlaps.
[image: Overlapping]

There is this thing over here as well.
[image: Front leg]

I've looked online, and didn't find much of what I was looking for. There were either different solutions for different shapes, or none at all. I was really invested in the tutorials and had fun moving along, but this wall is starting to bug me, and I would like to figure this out
EDIT: Here is the file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/6ulfx6lrcwbisaa/chaircopy.blend/file

Thank you

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: In the first picture the selected edges, could it be that they are overlapping. Means the left one comes from the right outer side and the right one from the left outer side. You can check it by selecting one of the involved vertices (let's say the right) and pressing "G" twice to slide it. If you can slide it past the left one, you have an overlap. As @moonboots already mentioned, sharing your file could allow for a more in depth check up. That said, **no one can/will force you to share the file.**

Comment: you didn't make a good "mark seam" and then unwrap UV messed it up. try to make a good mark seam

Comment: @moonboots I added the download link.

Comment: @Xylvier I did try that, having one side overlap the other, and it shows me which side is over which, but it does make the material look a bit worse.

Comment: @AkaiShuichi I was following the tutorial closely, the seams that I have marked are the same in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have non-connected edges and faces overlapping, I guess your problem comes from that, you need to correct this: Delete the faces loop, use the *Bridge* tool to reconnect the edges, mark seam again and unwrap.

[image]

Comment: I think that did it. Wow, it is like a breathe of fresh air. It is so much cleaner and better looking now, thank you so much